# Why does ifelse() return an integer value that is NOT a true or false argument r

Tags: r, if-statement

My df has two columns `a` and `b`. 
Rows that contain values for `a` are NAs in `b` and vice versa.
I wish to create a new column `ab` that will contain only values that are not NA

My data:

`df = data.frame (a = c(rep("c",4), (rep(NA,4))), b = c(rep(NA,4),rep("e",4)))`

I tried first using `dplyr`

```
df = df %>% 
  mutate (ab = ifelse (is.na (a), b, a))
```

and `base`

```
df$ab = ifelse (is.na(df$a), df$b, df$a)
```

The outcome is the same:

```
     a    b ab
1    c <NA>  1
2    c <NA>  1
3    c <NA>  1
4    c <NA>  1
5 <NA>    e  1
6 <NA>    e  1
7 <NA>    e  1
8 <NA>    e  1
```

My questions are:
1. Why does it returns a value that is not in any of the true or false arguments?
2. How can I create a column that combines `a` and `b` according to which ever is not NA? (preferably using `dplyr`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `factor` columns in the data. Your problem would be solved if you `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while constructing the dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame (a = c(rep("c",4), (rep(NA,4))), 
                 b = c(rep(NA,4),rep("e",4)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

However, `dplyr` has a nice `coalesce` function which does exactly does what you need without using `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(ab = coalesce(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ab := fcoalesce(a, b)][]
```